# Motivating the importance of energy

Tags: energy, education

I'm working on a project right now and part of the introduction is about energy, and I'm trying to introduce the notion of energy in an unconventional way. Right now, I am looking for examples of situations in physics and chemistry where energy plays a key role. Another way of putting it is: I am looking for questions where the answer is energy. I'm basically trying to motivate the concept of energy and demonstrate why it is important.

Does anybody have ideas of seemingly fundamental occurrences where a *true* answer is provided by the notion of energy? Thanks!

Comment: In your your previous answer it seems you have read feynman. Don't you find his explanation motivating?

Comment: @DSinghvi Feynman mentions energy several times. I'm not sure which particular occurrence you have in mind. Maybe a link to the particular section would help? The explanations I have read aren't good enough for me $-$ I'm trying to do something new, not something that has already been discussed and read many times.

Comment: "Make me a list" style questions are usually closed here to try and keep answers more narrow/focussed. If you can re-work this so that you're not asking for an open-ended list it's likely to get a better reception.

Comment: Generally speaking, whenever you meet someone who seeks for an "unconventional" explanation for something, the most obvious explanation is, that they don't understand the conventional one. So what, exactly, do you not understand about "the ability of a system to perform work"?

Answer (score 1):

Historically, one motivating experiment for kinetic energy was [dropping balls into clay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willem_%27s_Gravesande#Mechanics) and noting the relation between impact speed $v$ and the impact depth $d$: $$v^2 \propto d$$
I suspect this experiment could be modified to show the role that mass plays and obtain $d\propto mv^2$.

A different experiment would be to launch a cart using some type of [compressible hoop](http://www.vernier.com/products/accessories/hoops-blk/) and finding out what is the same about carts of different masses that are launched in identical ways. Various plotting techniques could then show all carts have the same quantity $mv^2$. More specifically, they have the same quantity $Q$ that can be written $Q=Q(mv^2)$.